# Biztalk split outbound flatfile limitting maximum records

Tags: split, biztalk, send

I am converting xml to a flat file using BizTalk.

There is a limitation of the number for records that can be contained in flat file.
When this limitation is exceeded I need to produces a 2nd (or 3rd or 4th) flat file with the remaining records and each file never exceeding that maximum.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your flat file?

Comment: No not really (customer permission). But it would seem to me that the precise format of the flat file really isn't that relevant. Lets just say we have an xml file with a list of people who have first name last names coming in. And we want a comma delimetted first,last coming out. With 1 person per line and no more than 3 people per file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/arnoudlems/archive/2006/02/15/69521.aspx). The idea here is:

1. You debatch your envelope schema within your orchestration (by executing the receive pipeline) and thus gain control over the debatched individual messages, using **Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.XLANGPipelineManager.ExecuteReceivePipeline**
2. You add the debatched individual messages, how many you want, to the send pipeline input messages using **Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.SendPipelineInputMessages**
3. Finally, you execute your sendpipeline within the orchestration using **Microsoft.XLANGs.Pipeline.XLANGPipelineManager.ExecuteSendPipeline** and passing it your SendPipelineInputMessages and your destination flat file envelope schema.

Check [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/sthomas/archive/2005/06/16/44023.aspx) for more clarity on debatching in your orchestration.